# Создать сайт без хостинга

Tags: сервер, сеть

Я конечно в этом не разбираюсь, и если что не так спросил, пожалуйста, не надо оскорблять. Так вот.

Хочется сделать свой **личный** сайт. Дело в том, что я не хочу пользоваться общественным хостингом. Хочется, чтобы ссылка на сайт была известна только мне и (можно так выразиться) доверенным лицам. Как раз нагрузка на сайт будет маленькая.

Можно же как-нибудь такое устроить?

[Правка {Желательно, чтобы данные сайта никто узнать не мог. Я конечно не разбираюсь в хостингах, но на всякий случай дополняю}]

Comment: Если у вас есть внешний IP - размещаете на нем web-сервер и готово. Хотя, это вы сами будете хостером, так что не подойдет :-D

Comment: где располагается сайт и его доступность по каким либо ссылкам не имеют друг к другу никакого отношения (почти). запросто можно сайт разместить на своем домашнем компе, при условии, что провайдер дает вам прямой (белый) ip. А ссылки - это вопрос DNS, если нужно имя, то в любом случае надо покупать доменное имя (у регистратора доменных имен, который к хостингу то же никакого отношения не имеет (хотя часто это она и та же контора). Если доменного имени нет, то на сайт можно будет попадать только по ip. Еще есть всякие сервисы DynDNS, на них бесплатно получить какую нибудь ссылку на ваш ip

Comment: Выделенный IP и сайт прямо по IP, без доменного имени. На домашнем компе. Все.

Comment: Можно пользоваться общественным хостингом, но сайт запаролить. А пароль сообщить "только мне и (можно так выразиться) доверенным лицам".

Comment: Можете поднять сайт на firebase или azure.microsoft).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для того чтобы сделать сайт тебе надо:
1 Узнать какой у тебя ip адрес статический или динамический. Эту информацию можно узнать у провайдера.
2 Определиться с веб сервером это зависит от операционной системы и того что ты хочешь от сайта.
3 Сам сайт.

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но что дальше? Я просто всё в интернете ищу с подробностями. Сам разбираюсь не очень.

Comment: Какой у тебя ип адрес?

Comment: Если динамический то попробуй noip.com

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сообщили ничего о том, что имеете как базу для такого желания. Поэтому ответы будут очень широкими. Если не вдаваться в подробности то план построения такой:

1. На домашний компьютер устанавливается программа web-сервер. Это может быть apache, nginx, lighttpd, iis в зависимости от операционной системы на домашнем компьютере. Кроме того вам скорее всего понадобится поддержка баз данных (например, mysql) и некоторых языков программирования (например, php), на которых обычно пишут сайты. Бывают и готовые наборы типа Denwer - при их установке вы фактически получите ранее указанные программы и они будут настроены для работы друг с другом.
2. После этого надо собственно создать ваш сайт. При этом вы можете задать и параметры зашиты от посторонних. Можно делать это как силами самого сайта так и силами web-сервера (например, можно запрашивать пароль при подключении к сайту). Есть еще возможность для открытых сайтов указать какую информацию должны игнорировать поисковики при сканировании сайта.
3. Обеспечить работу вашего "сервера" с внешним миром. Проверить настройки firewall/Брандмауэра. При наличии роутера для связи с внешним миром, сделать в нем настройки для доступа интернет пользователей к локальному компьютеру.
4. на этом этапе пользователи уже смогут заходить к вам по вашему ip адресу. Узнать адрес можно, например, зайдя на сайт 2ip.ru Как уже писали выше, этот адрес может быть постоянным или иногда меняться на другой в зависимости от способа работы вашего провайдера.
5. Если вы хотите купить имя/адрес для вашего сайта или достали бесплатный вариант, то на сайте dns-провайдера (того кто продает вам адрес) вы указываете соответствие этого адреса вашему ip-адресу. Если ip-адрес у вас не постоянный (динамический), то вам помогут провайдеры dynDns. В последнем случае, ваш компьютер или роутер (в зависимости от их возможностей и вашего способа подключения к интернету) самостоятельно будет подключаться к службе ddns и каждый раз указывать текущий ip-адрес

Вот как-то так...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com). Этот сервис бесплатный и Вы сможете хостить на нём простые веб-сайты(без php, простой html+css+js). Но такой сайт могут просамтривать все и, если не ошибаюсь, его код тоже.